# Good solution for storing a symmetric key or alternative way to secure my data

Tags: .net, security, cryptography

I have a particularly frustrating problem with regards to storing a symmetric key.

**BACKGROUND:**

I have some sensitive data stored in a database which needs to be encrypted/decrypted. Currently I am using the Rijndael algorithm. The application is web-based (ASP.NET MVC). The secret key needs to be the same across multiple instances (if those instances connect to the same DB).

**THE PROBLEM:**

Keeping in mind the above, where is the best place to store the secret key? Or perhaps I should be using an asymmetric algorithm? Someone also suggested to me to use a .cer file. How would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asymmetric encryption uses much higher resources in compare to symmetric. It's a good idea to encrypt data symmetrically and encrypt the key asymmetrically (like SSL).

Since you may need to have multiple instances the risk goes higher without a complementary asymmetric solution.

You have done the first part, just keep the keys safe with asymmetric algorithms through windows certificate management console (Run => `CertMgr.msc`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a good description of how crypto works on Windows/.NET. Basically you would store
your cert in a Windows certificate store and use the Crypt APIs to use it.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa388162(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0):

There aren't great solutions for storing a key. There are a lot of bad solutions, like hardcoding the key, or storing it in your database, so storing the key in a file like .cer idea is much better than those.

I've ported Google's [Keyczar](http://keyczar.org) framework [to C#](http://jbtule.github.com/keyczar-dotnet/), it stores the keys on the filesystem primarily. Emphasis on **keys** plural.

It has key rotation built into the format, so you can rotate your symmetric key over time, basically allowing you to replace or increase your key strength for new ciphertext without losing the ability to decrypt your old ciphertexts it does this by adding a small key identifier to the ciphertext and using [authenticated encryption](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption).

Being able to change your encryption key is something that is often over looked when building your own encryption.

Answer (score 0):

Use the single use, randomly generated, symmetric key. Add this key directly to the message, encrypting it with asymmetric encryption algorithm. The receiver first decodes the symmetric key and then uses it to decode the rest of the message; after that the symmetric key is discarded and never reused - so need not be stored.

You will get all logic of the asymmetric encryption and the size of the even good encryption key should not be a big performance problem.